# How to import specific function from cv2 (opencv)?

Tags: python, file, size, exe, opencv

How can I import only a specific function from cv2 (opencv) in python? I need only these function:

```
cv2.matchTemplate
cv2.minmaxLOC
cv2.cvtColor
cv2.color_RGB2BGR
cv2.TM_COEFF_NORMED
cv2.imread
```

I ask this question because I use pyinstaller --onefile to make python project one exe only. With standard import cv2 file is just too big (over 50mb).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can import the specific functions with `from library import function`

In your case, you can use;

```
from cv2 import matchTemplate, minMaxLoc, cvtColor, COLOR_RGB2BGR, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, imread
```